# Embed view into Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, tableau-api

How do you embed a Tableau report into sharepoint? I do not want to use a webpart to embed a webpage I just want the tableau report not the entire view that comes from the webpart I frame.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your Tableau server view in a browser, there is a button labelled Share. Clicking that shows you either a URL or snippet of html you can use to share your viz. That's an easy way to get started, but you can do a lot more.

To see the other options, parameters that may be useful to you, find examples, or to learn about the Javascript API, read the Tableau Server Admin Guide section on embedding views: http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#embed.htm